# MFC DrawText, vertical, DT_CALCRECT with lf_escapement = 900

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, rect, vertical-text

I'm working on a MFC project with some GDI drawings. 
I use `DC.DrawText` to draw a vertical text into a `DC` using a `LOGFONT` with `lfEscapement = 900`.
The text is output when i use `DT_NOCLIP` in the desired vertical formatting.
However to center this text i used a call to `DC.DrawText` with the `DT_CALCRECT` argument.
I recognized that, despite the text is indeed drawn vertically, the `CRect` has a larger width 
than height.
My intuition says me that a vertical drawn text should have a larger height than width.
I did not include the calculation for centering the text. The question is just about what i can rely upon when i implement that vertical centering.

Does `DC.DrawText` with `DT_CALCRECT` ignore escapement?

```
void CMFCFontTestDlg::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this); // Gerätekontext zum Zeichnen

  if (IsIconic())
  {
    ...
  }
  else
  {
    CDialogEx::OnPaint();

    CRect clTextRect;
    CFont myFont;

    myFont.CreateFont(12, 0, 900, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, _T("Tahoma"));

    CFont* oldFont = dc.SelectObject(&myFont);

    dc.DrawText(_T("000000"), clTextRect, DT_CALCRECT);
    clTextRect.MoveToXY(100, 100);

    dc.DrawText(_T("000000"), clTextRect, DT_NOCLIP);
    dc.SelectObject(oldFont);
  }
}
```

[image]
[image: Vertically formatted text in DC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about it in the remarks to the `DrawTextEx` function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtextexa.
However, please note that neither the documentation of `DrawText` does say anything about this nor the documentation of the `DT_CALCRECT` flag.
This is likely to be overseen if one uses `DrawText` and not `DrawTextEx`.
I informed MS about this via "Is this page helpful?" feedback possibility.

> Remarks
>
> The `DrawTextEx` function supports only fonts whose escapement and
>   orientation are both zero.
>
> The text alignment mode for the device context must include the
>   `TA_LEFT`, `TA_TOP`, and `TA_NOUPDATECP` flags.

Considering this the solution is to use some trigonometric calculation starting from the size determined for escapement = 0 and then calculate the topleft and bottomright points of the rotated rect.